# If else statement inside for loop trouble with Hashmaps

Tags: java, hashmap

Basically I am having trouble with my if statement. I would like it to say "No CDs found for " + val, however this is the output I am getting:

```
    Welcome to the CD Database
    Enter search, add, name, list, or quit:
    name
    Enter the full or partial name:
    asdfa
    Enter search, add, name, list, or quit:
```

as you can see it is not returning anything.

my code:

```
public void printByName(String val) {

    int i = 0;
    for (CompactDisc values : database.values()) {

        if (values.getArtist().contains(val)) {

            System.out.println(values);

        } else if (i > database.size() && !values.getArtist().contains(val)) {

            System.out.println("No CDs found for " + val);

        }

       i++; 
}
}
```

for some reason my counter is not iterating and this has been driving me crazy for hours.I want it to say no CDs found after it loops through the hashmap and does not find a partial match of the string the user entered

additional output:

```
Welcome to the CD Database
Enter search, add, name, list, or quit:
name
Enter the full or partial name:
Mo
Artist:Modest Mouse Title:We Were Dead Before the Ship Even Sank price:5.99
Artist:Thelonious Monk Title:Monk's Dream price:5.99
Enter search, add, name, list, or quit:
list
Artist:Isley Brothers Title:Funky Family price:5.99
Artist:Muddy Waters Title:At Newport price:6.99
Artist:Sly & The Family Stone Title:Greatest Hits price:6.99
Artist:Modest Mouse Title:We Were Dead Before the Ship Even Sank price:5.99
Artist:St. Germain Title:Tourist price:5.99
Artist:Bob Dylan Title:Desire price:6.99
Artist:The Beatles Title:Abbey Road price:6.99
Artist:Los Straitjackets Title:The Velvet Touch of... price:5.99
Artist:The Velvet Underground Title:Peel Slowly and See price:6.99
Artist:Thelonious Monk Title:Monk's Dream price:5.99
Enter search, add, name, list, or quit:
quit
Program ending.
```

Comment: You never use the counter `i` and I also don't see hashmaps being used anywhere.  What is the problem then?

Comment: the hashmap is declared in the beginning of my code as database(I only posted the one method), my problem is that it is not outputting "No CDs found for" + val

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a problem in your logic structure.
Your 'if' is inside your "loop" block. It must be outside. Take a look:

```
public void printByName(String val) {
    int i = 0;
    for (CompactDisc values : database.values()) {
        if (values.getArtist().contains(val)) {
            System.out.println(values);
            i++;
        }  
    }
    if (i==0) {
        System.out.println("No CDs found for " + val);
    }
}
```

Comment: What about the case where there be multiple non matches?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen The point was to iterate through all of the hashmap's values and then if there is no partial match then to tell the user it cannot find it, only has to tell the user once.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out.  I thought he wanted a positive/negative message for each entry in the catalog.

Comment: No problem! Thank you for helping!

Answer (score 1):

The condition `i > database.size()` will never be true because the loop will exit before `i` reaches the database size.  Try changing your code to this:

```
public void printByName(String val) {
    for (CompactDisc values : database.values()) {
        if (values.getArtist().contains(val)) {
            System.out.println(values);
        } else {
            System.out.println("No CDs found for " + val);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: it outputs No CDs found for adfd 10 times

Comment: it should only let the user know that there are no cds found once

Comment: Here is the output I am getting    

Welcome to the CD Database
Enter search, add, name, list, or quit:
name
Enter the full or partial name:
adfd
No CDs found for adfd
No CDs found for adfd
No CDs found for adfd
No CDs found for adfd
No CDs found for adfd
No CDs found for adfd
No CDs found for adfd
No CDs found for adfd
No CDs found for adfd
No CDs found for adfd

Answer (score 0):

It should be `else if (i >= database.size() && !values.getArtist().contains(val))`for the reason stated above.